# service-worker.js catch updatefound before running other custom functions

Tags: javascript, user-interface, service-worker, service-worker-events

Is there a way to check if the service worker found an update before loading custom functions?

i have this function which is working, but it runs the custom functions twice, and seems very untidy..

I'm looking for a way to only run the custom functions once, and not when an update was found and installed. When an update is found, the user || the page will reload automatically and then the custom functions can run normally..

I added the reg.events in this function to determine where to place my custom functions. I hope this question is understandable..

```
function installApp(path, scope) {
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(path, {
            scope: scope
        }).then((reg) => {  
       // event listener to catch the prompt if any and store in
      // an instance for later use with add to homescreen() function.
       getPrompt(); 

       // this is a custom alert type notification      
       makeProgress('System','is ok'); 
                    
      /* THIS IS THE UPDATE FOUND FUNCTION */

        reg.onupdatefound = function() {
    var installingWorker = reg.installing;
    installingWorker.onstatechange = function() {
      switch (installingWorker.state) {
        case 'installed':
          if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
     // the _clear() function removes items from the locaforage db to 
    // force the app to not auto login, but let the user
    // login again to refresh any data when the page reloads
                _clear('uuid');
                _clear('user');
                _clear('token');
                makeProgress('new version','reload app');
          } else {
           // removes any custom notifications
                    clearProgress(); 
            //just go into the app because everything is loaded.
            //We dont need to reinstall the 
            //homescreen or listen for the homescreen because this
           //is an update and the homescreen should already be installed?
               enterApp(); 
          }
          break;
        case 'redundant':
          // removes any custom notifications cause
          //the install is complete
            clearProgress();
               enterApp(); 
          console.log('The installing service worker became redundant.');
          break;
      }
    };
            return;
  };
                         


                  /** Here is the events that fire during the install
                 //  process and where i am currently stuck **/
  
    if (reg.installing) {
       makeProgress('updating','files');
    /* THE SERVICE WORKER IS DOWNLOADING THE CACHE FROM THE SERVER */
    } else if (reg.waiting) {

    /* what message here ?*/
    /* as far as i can tell, THE SERVICE WORKER IS WAITING FOR 
    *//*PREVIOUS SERVICE WORKER TO BEREFRESHED SO A RELOAD */
    /*UI SHOULD COME HERE??*/

    } else if (reg.active) {
    /* what message here ?*/
    /* IS THIS THE BEST PLACE TO RUN THE BELOW CUSTOM
    *//*FUNCTIONS?? WILL //THEY ALWAYS FIRE */
    }
                    


/** AT WHICH OF THE EVENTS ABOVE WILL I ADD THE FUNCTIONS FROM HERE **/

                requestWakeLock();  
       const browserFeatures = detectFeatures(reg);
               setCompatibilityArray(browserFeatures);
         
localforage.ready().then(function() {
                localforage.getItem('homescreen').then(function (value) {
               if(value != 1){           
    if (platform == 'iPhone' || platform == 'iPad') {
installHome();                                      
                                    } else {
     makeProgress('waiting', 'prompt');  
                         waitPrompt();
                         }
                         return;
               } else {
               enterApp();
                         return;        
               }
                         
    }).catch(function (err) {
    alertIt('something went wrong. Please refresh the page to try again.  If the problem persists, try another browser.</br>', 'warning', 0);
                    return;
    });
                
}).catch(function (err) {
  alertIt('Something went wrong.<br>Please refresh the page to restart the installation process.<br>'+err, 'danger', 0);
                return;
});
    
    
    /** TO HERE, WITHOUT RUNNING THESE FUNCTION DURING*/
   /*THE ONUPDATEFOUND EVENT AS THEN THEY WILL    RUN TWICE**/
    
    
    
        }, (err) => {
            alertIt('Something went wrong.<br>Please refresh the page to restart the   installation process.<br>', 'danger', 0);
        })
} else {
           alertIt('This browser is not compatible with this app.<br>Please try to use a   different browser to install this application.<br>', 'danger', 0);
   return;
}
}
```

I initialize this script like so:

```
  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
 makeProgress('Checking','system');     
  installApp(appsPath, appScope);
  })
```

Comment: can anybody help here??

Comment: What exactly is your problem statement? Do you want to invoke your function when service worker register or what are the conditions in which you would like to invoke this function.

Answer (score 0):

basically they must not be invoked if a new update is found..

I discovered that the onupdate function runs when old service worker is active..

If the onupdate function fires it changes a variable to a true value

I then used a time out function in the active event to see if a variable had changed... if it did change then i return false, and let the onupdate functions continue their course.. otherwise i continue to load my custom functions...Its working, but it doesn't seem like the best way.

Do you have a better method?

so like this:

```js
    function installApp(path, scope) {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(path, {
            scope: scope
        }).then((reg) => { 
       getPrompt(); 
       makeProgress('refreshing','files'); 
                    
    var entApp = true;
        reg.onupdatefound = function() {
    entApp = false;
    var installingWorker = reg.installing;
    installingWorker.onstatechange = function() {
      switch (installingWorker.state) {
        case 'installed':
          if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                _clear('uuid');
                _clear('user');
                _clear('token');
                makeProgress('new version','reloading app');
    setTimeout(function(){
    location.reload();
    }, 2500);
    return;
          } else {
      /*NOT SURE WHAT IS SUPPOSED TO GO HERE, SO I JUST RELOADED THE PAGE*/
                makeProgress('new version','reloading app');
    setTimeout(function(){
    location.reload();
    }, 2500);
    return;
          }
          break;
        case 'redundant':
      /*NOT SURE WHAT IS SUPPOSED TO GO HERE, SO I JUST RELOADED THE PAGE*/
                makeProgress('new version','reloading app');
    setTimeout(function(){
    location.reload();
    }, 2500);
    return;
          break;
      }
    };
            return;
     };
                         


    if (reg.active) {

    /** RIGHT HERE IS WHERE THE ONUPDATE FIRES. I GAVE IT A 
     2.5 SECONDS TO DO ITS THING, THEN CHECKED TO SEE IF THERE WAS
    AN UPDATE, IF NO UPDATE THEN I RUN MY CUSTOM FUNCTIONS, OTHERWISE
    THE ONUPDATE FUNCTION RELOADS THE PAGE AND THE UPDATED SW.JS FILE
    WILL THEN RUN THESE FUNCTIONS WHEN ITS ACTIVE.. IS THERE A BETTER
    IN-BUILT METHOD TO DO THIS?**/

    setTimeout(function(){
    if(entApp === true){
                requestWakeLock();  
       const browserFeatures = detectFeatures(reg);
               setCompatibilityArray(browserFeatures);
         
    localforage.ready().then(function() {
                localforage.getItem('homescreen').then(function (value) {
               if(value != 1){           
    if (platform == 'iPhone' || platform == 'iPad') {
    installHome();                                      
                                    } else {
     makeProgress('waiting', 'prompt');  
                         waitPrompt();
                         }
                         return;
               } else {
               enterApp();
                         return;        
               }
                         
    }).catch(function (err) {
    alertIt('something went wrong. Please refresh the page to try again.  If     the problem persists, try another browser.</br>', 'warning', 0);
                    return;
    });
                
    }).catch(function (err) {
    alertIt('Something went wrong.<br>Please refresh the page to restart the   installation process.<br>'+err, 'danger', 0);
                return;
    });

    }
    }, 2500);
    }
```

Comment: When answering a question, only submit answers that you think are correct. If you have a question about what he/she are doing then ask them with a comment on the post.